# What happens is the activity get killed by android before fragment commit actually happens?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

First of all I want to say sorry if my question is dummy, but I'm just starting my Android way. I'd like to understand what will happen If the activity will be killed by Android before committing fragment transaction. As far as I know `commit` is async, so it might happen some time in the future. So what would happen if I will start fragment transaction, e.g. add new fragment, and will send the app to the background where the activity will be killed by os(force activity killing by enabling debug options like "don't keep activities") before the actually executing `commit`. So when I'll return to the app and the activity will be recreated will it load the previous fragment or the one that I was trying to add(assuming I'm using `onSave/onRestoreInstance` state to save the current fragment)
Agin sorry for the dummy question, just trying to understand android

Comment: Have you ever encountered this? From what I know even "force kill activity" option gives apps a small (few seconds) window so it's almost impossible for it to happen before commit is executed (which usually happens within few milliseconds).

Comment: Pawel, thanks for the reply . Actually no, I never faced this . It is just a thought in my head , and I’m trying understand if this possible and what would happen if so .